# Write to Gridview Row when Linkbutton in Gridview clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` that has a Close `linkbutton` in each row. When the users Clicks in the Close `Button`, it should write the data to that particular row. My data already writes but I when I click for example in the third row `linkbutton` Close, then it writes to the first row. I want it to write to the third row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
Width="688px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
OnRowCommand="gvTransInfo_RowCommand">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction Type" SortExpression="TransTypeDesc">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLTrans" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTrans"
                DataTextField="TransTypeDesc" DataValueField="TransTypeId">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceTrans" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iQueueConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [TransTypeId], [TransTypeDesc] FROM [tblTransType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTrans" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TransTypeDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Received" HeaderText="Received" SortExpression="Received">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Complete" HeaderText="Complete" SortExpression="Complete">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TransTime" HeaderText="Est. Transaction Time" SortExpression="TransTime">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbClose" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="CloseClicked"
                OnClick="CloseClick_Click">Close</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="EditRow">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="DeleteRow">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="UpdateRow"
                Text="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TicketId")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="CancelUpdate"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TicketId")%>' Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
protected void CloseClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var StartLink = (Control)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)StartLink.NamingContainer;
        firstCellText = row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

Comment: what is the code of CloseClick_Click?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CommandField` with a `select` property instead of a `TemplateField` with a `LinkButton`

and in the `YourGridView_SelectedIndexChanged handler` use the `YourGridView.SelectedIndex` to work with the row you clicked.

you could then say:

```
firstCellText = row.Cells[YourGridView.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved. I just did a query and displayed it based on my firstcellText value, that fix the problem.